# Copying a tuple to an entire row in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to for loop through a dataframe and copy an entire row to a temporary dataframe. row is of type tuple so how do I copy each item in the tuple to a different column of the same row in a dataframe?  Please see the example of my dataframe and my desired output

Here is my dataframe df:

```
╔════════╦════════════════╦═════════════════════╦═══════════════════════╦═════════════╗
║   ID   ║      Name      ║       Address       ║         Email         ║    Items    ║
╠════════╬════════════════╬═════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 839843 ║ John Smith     ║ 55 Apple Lane       ║ jsmith@gmail.com      ║ 827,937,392 ║
║ 327569 ║ Tom Hanks      ║ 16 Cauliflower Road ║ thanks@gmail.com      ║ 947,540     ║
║ 924852 ║ Alison Johnson ║ 85 Main Street      ║ Ajohnson@yahoo.com    ║ 838         ║
║ 949325 ║ Frank Rizzo    ║ 218 Orange Road     ║ frizzo313@hotmail.com ║ 494,386,285 ║
║ 373202 ║ Kelly Chang    ║ 19 First Avenue     ║ kchang@gmail.com      ║ 928,502,214 ║
║ 928436 ║ Lisa Thomas    ║ 95 Albany Way       ║ lthomas@hotmail.com   ║ 455,953     ║
╚════════╩════════════════╩═════════════════════╩═══════════════════════╩═════════════╝
```

This is my desired output:

```
╔════════╦══════╦════════════════╦═════════════════════╦═══════════════════════╗
║   ID   ║ Item ║      Name      ║       Address       ║         Email         ║
╠════════╬══════╬════════════════╬═════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╣
║ 839843 ║  827 ║ John Smith     ║ 55 Apple Lane       ║ jsmith@gmail.com      ║
║ 839843 ║  937 ║ John Smith     ║ 55 Apple Lane       ║ jsmith@gmail.com      ║
║ 839843 ║  392 ║ John Smith     ║ 55 Apple Lane       ║ jsmith@gmail.com      ║
║ 327569 ║  947 ║ Tom Hanks      ║ 16 Cauliflower Road ║ thanks@gmail.com      ║
║ 327569 ║  540 ║ Tom Hanks      ║ 16 Cauliflower Road ║ thanks@gmail.com      ║
║ 924852 ║  838 ║ Alison Johnson ║ 85 Main Street      ║ Ajohnson@yahoo.com    ║
║ 949325 ║  494 ║ Frank Rizzo    ║ 218 Orange Road     ║ frizzo313@hotmail.com ║
║ 949325 ║  386 ║ Frank Rizzo    ║ 218 Orange Road     ║ frizzo313@hotmail.com ║
║ 949325 ║  285 ║ Frank Rizzo    ║ 218 Orange Road     ║ frizzo313@hotmail.com ║
║ 373202 ║  928 ║ Kelly Chang    ║ 19 First Avenue     ║ kchang@gmail.com      ║
║ 373202 ║  502 ║ Kelly Chang    ║ 19 First Avenue     ║ kchang@gmail.com      ║
║ 373202 ║  215 ║ Kelly Chang    ║ 19 First Avenue     ║ kchang@gmail.com      ║
║ 928436 ║  455 ║ Lisa Thomas    ║ 95 Albany Way       ║ lthomas@hotmail.com   ║
║ 928436 ║  953 ║ Lisa Thomas    ║ 95 Albany Way       ║ lthomas@hotmail.com   ║
╚════════╩══════╩════════════════╩═════════════════════╩═══════════════════════╝
```

This is the code I have to solve the problem but so far without success:

```
temp_df = df.iloc[:0] 

c=0
i=0
for row in df.iterrows():
    items = row[1][4].split(',') 
    for item in items:            
        temp_df.at[i+c,:] = row
        temp_df.at[-1, 'Items'] = item
        c=c+1
    i=i+c
    c=0
```

Hopefully someone can help with a solution.

Comment: df.explosion should do it easily

Comment: I just read about df.explode and it sounds like it could work but how would I use it since I am first splitting my item column into a seperate list?

Comment: If your items column is a tuple, use df.explode(‘items’)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that *your_file.csv* is the first table mentioned in your example, you can read it into `df` and:

### Solution 1:

Parse its rows to get what you need in `temp_df`:

```py
temp_df_records = []

for _, row in df.iterrows():
    items = row["Items"].split(',')
    row_dict = row.drop("Items").to_dict()
    for item in items:
        row_dict["Item"] = item
        temp_df_records.append(row_dict.copy())

temp_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(temp_df_records)
```

### Solution 2:

You can convert the values of column "Items" to list and use `.explode()` method to construct `temp_df`:

```py
temp_df = df.copy().rename(columns={"Items": "Item"})
temp_df["Item"] = temp_df["Item"].apply(lambda items: items.split(","))
temp_df = temp_df.explode("Item").reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

Output (`temp_df`) in both solutions:

```
        ID            Name              Address                  Email Item
0   839843      John Smith        55 Apple Lane       jsmith@gmail.com  827
1   839843      John Smith        55 Apple Lane       jsmith@gmail.com  937
2   839843      John Smith        55 Apple Lane       jsmith@gmail.com  392
3   327569       Tom Hanks  16 Cauliflower Road       thanks@gmail.com  947
4   327569       Tom Hanks  16 Cauliflower Road       thanks@gmail.com  540
5   924852  Alison Johnson       85 Main Street     Ajohnson@yahoo.com  838
6   949325     Frank Rizzo      218 Orange Road  frizzo313@hotmail.com  494
7   949325     Frank Rizzo      218 Orange Road  frizzo313@hotmail.com  386
8   949325     Frank Rizzo      218 Orange Road  frizzo313@hotmail.com  285
9   373202     Kelly Chang      19 First Avenue       kchang@gmail.com  928
10  373202     Kelly Chang      19 First Avenue       kchang@gmail.com  502
11  373202     Kelly Chang      19 First Avenue       kchang@gmail.com  214
12  928436     Lisa Thomas        95 Albany Way    lthomas@hotmail.com  455
13  928436     Lisa Thomas        95 Albany Way    lthomas@hotmail.com  953
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: this solution doesnt work because my row has multiple columns and I get this error 'ValueError: Length of values (1) does not match length of index (73)'

Comment: @Samir112 this is because the first version of your question was very vague and unclear. Now that you've edited the question and made it understandable, I did the same with the answer and I think it works now.

Comment: Thank you @msamsami I prefer and implemented solution 2 as it is faster and more efficient!